# What indexes to apply on normalized SQL database?

Tags: sql, database, key

I'm normalizing my database structure, but I am not entirely sure what indexes to apply. I have the following structure:

My Profiles table has 2 columns (profile_id, profile_name), my keyword table has 2 columns (keyword_id, keyword_name) and my profiles_keyword table has 2 columns (profile_id, keyword_id).

Would it make sense to apply indexes to all columns? Should I make a PRIMARY COMPOSITE key on profile_id,keyword_id? I should also add referential keys to the profiles_keyword table?

Not sure which is best and what key doens't work with the other!

Thanks.

Comment: Use the execution plan for queries you run against your data. It will tell you when an index is missing. Outside of PK's and FK's, which indexes you need depend on how you query your data.

Comment: Note that primary keys are there to make a record unique which enables you to identify it.  Keep that in mind regarding your decision about a composite primary key.  Having said that, for what you described, it seems like the right way to go.

Answer (score 1):

There are two related, but conceptually separate concepts at play here.

Firstly, there is the concept of keys - primary and foreign. These are conceptual entities, identifying the nature of your tables and their relationships. For instance, a primary key says "this is how you uniquely identify one row from another in this table". In principle, a "key" doesn't have a physical presence by itself.

Keys are often implemented with an index - a primary key requires a unique index, for instance. I recommend you apply indices to your primary and foreign keys.

An index is a physical thing - it exists on your hard drive. You use an index for two reasons: to give physical shape to your keys (see above), and to optimize queries. For instance, even though "profile_name" and "keyword_name" are not keys in your schema, it's likely that they will be required for searching. Therefore, you will probably need an index on those columns.

Comment: PK index is not only unique, it's also *clustered* :)

Comment: Not always - not every database engine supports clustered indices. Of course, if your database supports it, it's nearly always a good idea to use clustered unique indices for primary keys.

Answer (score 0):

On profiles_keyword you should add 2 foreign keys, one to each table.

It is a good practice to add indexes for every column you add a FK for, so 2 indexes are required there.

According to your queries you should decide if to also add an index for the 2 columns together.

If you do selects by name from the `Profiles` table or from the `keyword` table you can and indexes on the `Name` columns, but you will need to consider that indexes on string fields take much more space on the disk.

For all indexes remember that you pay in execution times on inserts and updates since the DB needs to update the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Since they are primary keys, both profile_id and keyword_id are automatically indexed, in order to optimize joins. You need the composite primary key on the relation table only to ensure uniqueness of pairs, if this is not a constraint, i.e. the same profile can be related more times with the same keyword, that index is not required. However you can just create a non unique index to optimize join performance. Anyway would be good specify foreign keys to properly manage relation between entities integrity.

Comment: The database engine is not mentioned, but are there any that do not automatically index primary keys?

Comment: @DanBracuk You're right I've edited my answer